# POST and PUT requests not working on IOS in Ionic3 App even if when moving to HTTPS give me ssl error (SSL handshake)

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework, http-post

I'm having an issue with HTTP requests. Everything is working fine in Ionic View, browser and Android, but not working on IOS. GET requests are working fine on IOS also, but post and put requests aren't.I searched for that and I found that I should move to HTTPS and when I do that I receive SSL errors (ssl handshake). Any guesses, what should I do?
the same issue mentioned here, but that answer didn't work for me
[POST requests not working on IOS in Ionic2 App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41872521/post-requests-not-working-on-ios-in-ionic2-app/57677969#57677969)

After investigating my code, I find out that in IOS when posting a JSON object it changes the order of attribute, so while I have an attribute that refer to another brings it in top so that makes the problem. How to solve this please? that issue cost me a lot of time .

Comment: Please add more details about what you tried so far.

Comment: I read that Apple decided to enforce the use of HTTPS, so I move to HTTPS but I get that SSL error (An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made.)

Comment: have you tried this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32755674/ios9-getting-error-an-ssl-error-has-occurred-and-a-secure-connection-to-the-ser

Comment: @ZulqarnainJalil yes NSAllowsArbitraryLoads already set to true.

Comment: check your device date and time... it should be correct... !

Comment: @ZulqarnainJalil it is